# Problem splitting XML into multiple files using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to create an XSL transform that splits an XML document into multiple files that conform to the same schema. The issue I'm having is that my XSLT outputs a single file with the content and no XML tags. I've read similar posts in this forum but I don't seem to be able to fix this. A sample of my source XML and XSLT are below.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Sample of the source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<inm:Results productTitle="Inmagic DB/TextWorks" productVersion="17.0" xmlns:inm="http://www.inmagic.com/webpublisher/query">
<inm:Recordset setCount="4">
<inm:Record setEntry="0">
<inm:Title>Portraits</inm:Title>
<inm:DateRange>[ca. 1955]-[ca. 1973]</inm:DateRange>
<inm:FondsNo>18</inm:FondsNo>
<inm:SeriesNo>1</inm:SeriesNo>
<inm:FileNo />
<inm:ItemNo />
<inm:AccessionNo>2005-2-1</inm:AccessionNo>
<inm:AcquisitionSource />
<inm:CustodialHistory />
</inm:Record>
<inm:Record setEntry="1">
<inm:Title>John Smith</inm:Title>
<inm:DateRange>[ca. 1960]</inm:DateRange>
<inm:FondsNo>18</inm:FondsNo>
<inm:SeriesNo>1</inm:SeriesNo>
<inm:FileNo />
<inm:ItemNo>1</inm:ItemNo>
<inm:AccessionNo />
<inm:AcquisitionSource />
<inm:CustodialHistory />
</inm:Record>
<inm:Record setEntry="2">
<inm:Title>John and Danielle Smith</inm:Title>
<inm:DateRange>[ca. 1965]</inm:DateRange>
<inm:FondsNo>18</inm:FondsNo>
<inm:SeriesNo>1</inm:SeriesNo>
<inm:FileNo />
<inm:ItemNo>2</inm:ItemNo>
<inm:AccessionNo />
<inm:AcquisitionSource />
<inm:CustodialHistory />
</inm:Record>
<inm:Record setEntry="3">
<inm:Title>Luke Smith</inm:Title>
<inm:DateRange>[ca. 1960]</inm:DateRange>
<inm:FondsNo>18</inm:FondsNo>
<inm:SeriesNo>1</inm:SeriesNo>
<inm:FileNo />
<inm:ItemNo>3</inm:ItemNo>
<inm:AccessionNo />
<inm:AcquisitionSource />
<inm:CustodialHistory />
</inm:Record>
</inm:Recordset>
</inm:Results>
```

Its the content within the Record tags that I'm hoping to have in separate files.

And my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:inm="http://www.inmagic.com/webpublisher/query">

<xsl:output name="xml" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/Results/Recordset/Record">
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="file_{@setEntry}-output.xml">
      <Record>
        <xsl:copy-of select="/Record/@*" />
      </Record>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm using Saxon and executing it with a Power Shell command.

Comment: Which version of Saxon exactly do you use, which command do you use in PowerShell?

Comment: I'm using Saxon 9 HE and the Power Shell command is `PS C:\Users\David\Desktop\XSLT_Test> java -jar c:\saxon\saxon9he.jar -s:Input -xsl:Split4.xsl -o:Output`

Comment: In Saxon 10 there is a new command line switch to select elements in a namespace, otherwise use `xpath-default-namespace` or the prefix you have declared. It is not clear how a single file should look exactly.

Comment: When I add the prefix it creates separate files (so progress there), but they are all empty - no content, no mark ups. What am I missing?

Comment: It would be easier for us if you edited your question and showed the current code and the results you want and the ones you get. If files are created I would guess they contain an empty `<Record/>` element at least; the `<xsl:copy-of select="/Record/@*" />` is kind of odd as there are no attributes at all it seems and as of course inside of the `for-each` the context node is the currently processed `Record`, so you either don't need the literal `Record` you output but simply do `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` or you copy the children with `<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>`.

Comment: Working now. I add <xsl:value-of> elements for all of the tags I wanted in the output file and it seems to be working. Thank you, Martin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Martin and Sebastien! The XSLT works and I'm happy with the output files. Following everyone's advice, the final XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:inm="http://www.inmagic.com/webpublisher/query">

<xsl:output name="xml" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/inm:Results/inm:Recordset/inm:Record">
    <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="file_{@setEntry}-output.xml">
        <inm:Record>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
        </inm:Record>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You're welcome. If your question is answered please accept an answer and mark this is as closed.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you are not referencing your nodes using the namespace.
You should be using it like this :

```
<xsl:for-each select="inm:Results/inm:Recordset/inm:Record">
```

Second thing, in your code your are trying to copy the Record attributes

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/Record/@*" />
```

but your context is already a Record. So you should only be selecting attributes using @* or to make it clearer you could simply name the only attribute in Record, @setEntry.